# How to delete a cardview from recyclerView and sqlite database? (Kotlin - Android)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I'm creating an app with a recycler view, card view, and SQLite database. The card view contains a title, description, and a delete icon (On Item Click). When the user enters some data in the card view, it is displayed in recycler view and also added to the database.

**What I want:** I want to delete the required card view from the database and also from recycler view at the same time when I click the delete icon in the card view.

**The problem**:
let's say that I've added 3 card views when I click the delete icon on one of them it disappears but a copy of the last added card view appears at the bottom, so the number of the card views remain the same (3 cards) please check the images below.

**Code of recycler view adapter:**

```
class BillsAdapter(val bills: List<Bill>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BillsAdapter.BillViewHolder>() {

private var mListener: OnItemClickListener? = null

interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onDeleteClick(position: Int)
}

fun setOnClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener) {
    mListener = listener
}

class BillViewHolder( val card: View, listener: OnItemClickListener?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(card) {
    var mDeleteImage: ImageView

    init {
        mDeleteImage = card.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete)

        mDeleteImage.setOnClickListener {
            if (listener != null) {
                val position = adapterPosition
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    listener.onDeleteClick(position)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BillViewHolder, index: Int) {

    val bill = bills[index]

    holder.card.tv_title.text = bill.title
    holder.card.tv_description.text = bill.description


}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BillViewHolder {

    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.single_card, parent, false)

    return BillViewHolder(view, mListener)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = bills.size
```

**Code of DB Handler:**

```
class billDbHandler (context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context,
DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {

private val SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE ${BillEntry.TABLE_NAME} (" +
        "${BillEntry._ID} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
        "${BillEntry.TITLE_COL} TEXT," +
        "${BillEntry.DESCR_COL} TEXT," +
        ")"

private val SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${BillEntry.TABLE_NAME}"

override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES)
}

override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES)
    onCreate(db)
}
```

}

**Code of DB Table:**

```
class BillDbTable(context: Context) {

private val TAG = BillDbTable::class.java.simpleName
private val dbHelper = billDbHandler(context)

fun store(bill: Bill): Long {
    val db  = dbHelper.writableDatabase
    val values = ContentValues()

    values.put(BillEntry.TITLE_COL, bill.title)
    values.put(BillEntry.DESCR_COL, bill.description)

    val id = db.insert(BillEntry.TABLE_NAME, null,values)

    db.close()

    Log.d(TAG, "Stored new bill to DB $bill")

    return id
}

fun readAllBills(): List<Bill> {
    val columns = arrayOf(BillEntry._ID,
        BillEntry.TITLE_COL, BillEntry.DESCR_COL)

    val order = "${BillEntry._ID} ASC"

    val db= dbHelper.readableDatabase

    val cursor = db.doQuery(BillEntry.TABLE_NAME, columns, orderBy = order)

    return  parseBillsFrom(cursor)

}

fun parseBillsFrom(cursor: Cursor): MutableList<Bill> {
    val bills = mutableListOf<Bill>()
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        val title = cursor.getString(BillEntry.TITLE_COL)
        val desc = cursor.getString(BillEntry.DESCR_COL)

        bills.add(Bill(title, desc))
    }
    cursor.close()

    return bills
}

fun delete() {

    val columns = arrayOf(BillEntry._ID,
        BillEntry.TITLE_COL, BillEntry.DESCR_COL)

    val order = "${BillEntry._ID} ASC"

    val db = dbHelper.writableDatabase
    val cursor = db.doQuery(BillEntry.TABLE_NAME, columns, orderBy = order)

    if (cursor.moveToNext()){
        val id = cursor.getLong(0)
        db.delete(BillEntry.TABLE_NAME, BillEntry._ID + "= ?" , arrayOf(id.toString()))
        cursor.close()
     }

    db.close()
  } }    fun SQLiteDatabase.doQuery(table: String, columns: Array<String>, selection: String? = null,
                               selectionArgs: Array<String>? = null, groupBy: String? = null,
                               having: String? = null, orderBy: String? = null): Cursor {
return query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy)}    private fun Cursor.getString(columnName: String): String = this.getString(getColumnIndex(columnName))
```

**Code of Main Activity:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var db = BillDbTable(this)
private var mAdapter: BillsAdapter? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    mAdapter = BillsAdapter(db.readAllBills())

    rv.setHasFixedSize(true)

    rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    rv.adapter = mAdapter

    mAdapter!!.setOnClickListener(object : BillsAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
        override fun onDeleteClick(position: Int) {
            removeCard(position)

        }
    })
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId == R.id.add_bill){
        val intent = Intent(this, CreateBillActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    return true
}

fun test() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Item Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

fun removeCard(position: Int){

    db.delete()
    test()
    mAdapter!!.notifyItemRemoved(position)


} }
```

Before clicking the delete icons of all cards

[image]

After clicking the delete icons of all cards
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possible strategies, here are two:

- You either need to reload the list from the DB, tracking diffs, or
- You need to manage the stored items list (e..g. `bills`) by removing items from it as you delete from the DB.

The way you have your adapter set up is that the initializing caller owns the items list. It's not usually a good idea for the adapter to modify a list passed to it, you need to either copy to a mutable collection, or reload.

You also need to call [notifyItemRemoved](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRemoved(int)), [notifyItemRangeRemoved](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyitemrangeremoved) or [notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifydatasetchanged) (depending on how you implement removal) on the adapter after making your removal changes.

You may also want to look into [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil).

Comment: I'll take a look at diffutil, and thanks for the clarification.